# Why am I getting a memory access violation here?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, webserver

[This file](http://approsoftware.com/download/rtl8181/SDK/rtl8181-adk-1.5/rtl8181-ASP-1.5/AP/goahead-2.1.1/balloc.c) is part of the [GoAhead WebServer](http://www.goahead.com/products/webserver/default.aspx), that implements a very fast block allocation scheme.

At line 284 the web server process crashes, at random times.

```
 } else if ((bp = bQhead[q]) != NULL) {
/*
 *  Take first block off the relevant q if non-empty
 */
  bQhead[q] = bp->u.next; //MEMORY ACCESS VIOLATION HERE
```

What are the possible reasons for this?

**EDIT**
bp is a pointer to this structure and union in [this header file](http://approsoftware.com/download/rtl8181/SDK/rtl8181-adk-1.5/rtl8181-ASP-1.5/AP/goahead-2.1.1/uemf.h)

```
typedef struct {
    union {
        void    *next;                          /* Pointer to next in q */
        int     size;                           /* Actual requested size */
    } u;
    int         flags;                          /* Per block allocation flags */
} bType;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is u? We need more inforation

Comment: Surely you already know what the possible reasons are. An AV occurs when you address memory that's not in your process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the possible reasons.

- You've screwd something up and corrupted some of your data structures or your stack.
- `bQhead` is a NULL or invalid pointer
- `q` is outside the bounds of `bQhead`
- `bp` is a NULL or invalid pointer

Step through the code with a debugger, or use printf debugging, and see if the values if bQhead,q,bp are what they should be.

Comment: Some debuggers will also tell you the address of the invalid access, or the instruction (at which case you can observe the registers it references), which will also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Give us more hints ...

Probably memory corruption by another thread, if it is random ...

my2c

Comment: How can I figure out if another thread is the issue, what would I look for in this case?

Comment: The best thing to do is to try some memory debuger to check corruption. I use valgrind on linux. I have used (a long time ago) electric fence. You can try this sort of thing. Concerning threading, you can try static analysis : look for any thread that use your data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Without running under a debugger, I would guess that q is out of range of 0 to B_MAXCLASS-1.  The function that sets q, `ballocGetSize()` does not do any bounds checking to make sure the block class stays within bounds.

A simple assertion to check that q is within bounds before deferencing would rule that possibilty out.

Comment: I think the main "if" statement of this "else if" is checking this, correct? "if (q >= B_MAX_CLASS) {" line 246

Comment: Ah, yes it is.  And looking at ballocGetSize(), q can't be negative (unless it rolls around as a negative int..)   So it may be corruption of the array itself.